# How to query OSM server for supported zoomlevels?

Tags: openstreetmap

OpenStreetMap tile servers usually have 20 zoomlevels, but some have a different number. Is there a standard way to query the number of zoomlevels a tile server supports?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. They are just "dumb" static file hosts with no knowledge of that they are serving.

Comment: This is not entirely true when using the [mod_tile](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mod_tile) apache module.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps but [mod_tile](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mod_tile) provides some debugging information under http://your.server/mod_tile.